# Spider identification Delaware

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

It looks like a wolf spider, but I've not seen these exact markings.

[image]

Comment: It could help if you gave indications of the size and environment.

Answer (score 2):

That's a nice female Dolomedes tenebrosus - the upland Fishing Spider that lives in similar habitat to Wolf Spiders, and eats the same sort of foods.
The way it holds its long, stripey legs together (the front pair, anyway) is pretty standard for the Pisauridae, and the pattern on the body (while a bit variable in this species) is pretty distinctive.

https://bugguide.net/node/view/2011

[image]